# Sum All elements of each array in an array of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have this dictionary:

```
import numpy as np
dict={'W1': np.array([[ 1.62434536, -0.61175641, -0.52817175], 
                     [-1.07296862,  0.86540763, -2.3015387 ]]), 
     'b1': np.array([[ 1.74481176], 
                     [-0.7612069 ]]), 
     'W2': np.array([[ 0.3190391 , -0.24937038], 
                     [ 1.46210794, -2.06014071], 
                     [-0.3224172 , -0.38405435]]), 
     'b2': np.array([[ 1.13376944], 
                     [-1.09989127], 
                     [-0.17242821]]), 
     'W3': np.array([[-0.87785842,  0.04221375,  0.58281521]]), 
     'b3': np.array([[-1.10061918]])}
```

I need to sum all the elements of W1, W2, W3 after squared them, each one at a time then all of the three.

I used this to extract a list with the keys W(i)

```
l=[v for k, v in dict.items() if 'W' in k]
```

How could I get the sum of the squared elements in each array?
When taken each array separately I do:

```
 np.sum(np.square(l[0]) to get 10.4889815722 for l[0]
```

I don't know though how to sum them all in one shot

Comment: I'm a bit confused how you get these numbers. Which elements add up to `10.4889815722` for example?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I forget to say that I do square the elements before adding them up for 10.4889815722 that's np.sum(np.square(l[0]). Question edited to reflect that.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I got you, but here's what I think you're looking for:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = [np.array([1.62434536, -0.61175641, -0.52817175]), np.array([-1.07296862, 0.86540763, -2.3015387])]
>>> [np.sum(arr) for arr in data]
[0.48441719999999999, -2.5090996900000002]
```

Comment: That answers my question.  I needed only to add np.square to get the desired result. Thank you !

Comment: why not just `np.sum(data, axis=1)` in this case? this avoids the list comprehension...

Comment: @F.M.F. I thought the same. But I think there is a problem when the sub-arrays, that are within the array, have different lengths. E.g. `np.sum([array([ 1, 10]), array([ 1, 20])], axis=1)` works well, but `np.sum([array([ 1, 10, 15]), array([ 1, 20])], axis=1)` throws an error, because the one subarray has 3 and the other 2 elements. Pls, let me know if you have an idea how to avoid the error

Answer (score 1):

You could simply extract the sum of all values with a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> res = {key: np.square(arr).sum() for key, arr in dct.items()}  # you could also use if 'W' in key here too.
>>> res
{'W1': 10.48898156439229,
 'W2': 6.7973615015702658,
 'W3': 1.1120909752613031,
 'b1': 3.6238040224419072,
 'b2': 2.5249254365039309,
 'b3': 1.2113625793838725}
```

Given that dictionaries are unordered having the result as a dictionary is probably better (accessible with `res['W1']` for example) because otherwise the list elements would be in arbitrary order (or you need to sort the keys before putting them in a list).

To sum all `W*` values:

```
>>> sum(v for k, v in res.items() if 'W' in k)  # normal sum this time but would also work with np.sum!
18.398434041223858
```